# WPF (XAML) Binding within a ListBox ItemTemplate

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding

I have a Window that has a `ContentControl` which is styled using a `ContentTemplate`.

The `ContentTemplate` contains a simple `ListBox` nested inside a `Grid`. The Grid has the `DataContext` property set using code (bound to a `CollectionViewSource` - lets call it cvs1). The ListBox `ItemsSource` inherits from the Grid and population of the ListBox items is working fine. e.g.

```
<Grid x:Name="Grid1">
    <ListBox x:Name="ListBox1" ItemsSource="{Binding}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"/>
</Grid>
```

The ListBox is being styled, the main style is stored in a ResourceDictionary.

I'm setting style values for the ListBox using an `ItemTemplate`, but what I also want is to use a `DataTrigger` to dynamically apply different Setters. The challenge I'm facing is I can't seem to establish Binding within the DataTrigger(s) to a separate CollectionViewSource (let's call it cvs2).

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <!-- This seems to be trying to bind to cvs1, the error is it can't find the property -->
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding cvs2, Path=TemplateName}" Value="ABC">
            <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
        </DataTrigger>

        <!-- This just doesn't seem to work -->
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvs2},Path=TemplateName}" Value="XYZ">
            <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Both cvs1 and cvs2 are defined in a `ResourceDictionary`.

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="cvs1" />
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="cvs2" />
```

And then referenced as follows:

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="DataSources.xaml" />
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

The problem I seem to be facing is the `ItemTemplate` is inheriting the DataContext from the ListBox and I can't seem to get around this to establish binding to the cvs2 data source. I thought this would be a fairly routine `StaticResource` binding task. Seems that's not the case.

I have tested the following code in a Label outside the Grid (in the main Window) to debug the data:

```
<Label Content="{Binding cvs2, Path=/TemplateName}"/>
```

That works, the Label is populated with the value of TemplateName.

However, if I use this on the `DataTrigger` within the `ItemsTemplate`, the binding is not established.

How do I establish a binding to cvs2 from within the `ItemTemplate`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a silverlight developer and I just use Converters on bindings to achieve these type goals.

But I like Xaml and as I understand from your xaml depending on your cvs2 object's TemplateName property you would like to change ItemTemplate,Isn't it?

If so why don't you give us the value to ItemTemplate property?

```
      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvs2},
                   Path=TemplateName}" Value="XYZ">
        <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <TextBlock Text={Binding}/>
            <Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </DataTrigger>
     // When cvs2.TemplateName=XYZ use this template, isn't it?
```

Does cvs2 loaded first as a resource before this resource?

Is there any binding error on output?

You may try giving spesific style instead of implicit by x:Key.

Value converters may help you.

If you use StaticResource  it looks hierarchically bottom to top from key , so I don't think it search its from ListBox's datacontext.

I'm not answered quite yet maybe but hope give you an idea.